# CMAKE adding gcov options for C++ compiler

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, mingw-w64

I am in need to debug a flow hence compiling its code using cmake / mingw64 C++ compiler. I understand that if we compile with -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage for each source code file - I would get debug flow execution details thereby helping me to understand & fix the flow. So I added the below CMAKE options in my CMakelists.txt but I get mentioned error then:

```
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS    "-fprofile-arcs -fprofile-generate -lgcov --coverage")
add_definitions(${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS})
SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}" )
SET( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS}" )
```

Error during build - linking:

```
[76/150] Linking CXX executable test.exe
FAILED: test.exe
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\tools\mingw64\bin\c++.exe -DGSL_THROW_ON_CONTRACT_VIOLATION -Wall -ftrack-macro-expansion=0 -Werror -std=gnu++14 -D _SILENCE_TR1_NAMESPACE_DEPRECATION_WARNING -Og -g3   test.cpp.obj testhelp.cpp.obj  -o test.exe -Wl,--out-implib,test.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  ext/googletest/build/googlemock/libgmock_main.a -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
test/case/TestArgs.cpp.obj: In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_65535_0__ZN2cc5shell30TestCommandArguments_Size_Test10test_info_E':
:(.data+0x2ee0): undefined reference to `__gcov_merge_add'
In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_65535_0__ZN2cc5shell58TestArgumentCompletion_arg_root_2_subgroups_empty_arg_Test10test_info_E':
: undefined reference to `__gcov_init'
: undefined reference to `__gcov_merge_add'
```

I tried various options to resolve it - but it is not helping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linker option `-lgcov` is actually **linking with** "gcov" **library**, so it is better to mark it so:

```
link_libraries(gcov)
```

Difference between `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` variable and `link_libraries`/`target_link_libraries` commands is that the variable adds linker flags to the link command line **before** the object files, but the commands add linker flags **after** the object files. This difference is crucial in symbols resolving, when incorrect order of libraries and object files gives `undefined reference` error.